# is there any way to set Source for Image From .standard Class Library in UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I have create Xamarin Native App only create UI Part platform specfic and shared code(Model,ViewModel) using .net stadard class Library.
In UWP Project I set Source Path Like this

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/MyClassLibraryName;Component/Assets/AppLogo.png"
```

It does not work for me!

Comment: In UWP Project I set Source Path Like this
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MyClassLibraryName;Component/Assets/AppLogo.png" 
    Height="40"
     Stretch="UniformToFill"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have create Xamarin Native App only create UI Part platform specfic and shared code(Model,ViewModel) using .net stadard class Library

For this scenario, you could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#xaml) that make `ImageResourceExtension` to load the  `Embedded` image from .net stadard class Library.

We need add the following code to **.net stadard class Library**.

```
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
[ContentProperty(nameof(Source))]
public class ImageExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Source == null)
            return null;

        // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
        var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(ImageExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        return imageSource;
    }
}
```

Then add image file to .net standard class library and edit the Build Action to **Embedded**

**Usage**

```
ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:mySource="clr-namespace:ImageLib;assembly=ImageLib"
            x:Class="WorkingWithImages.EmbeddedImagesXaml">
   <StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,20">
       <Image Source="{mySource:Image ImageLib.logo.jpg}" />
   </StackLayout>
/ContentPage>
```

Please note: Image path is **classlibname.imagename.jpg**

**Update**

You could use uwp uri scheme to add the image path to imgage control, for example

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Image/AppLogoicon.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="Image" />
```

Comment: As Provided by you code it will be Support if we use  ContentPage in UWP Platform  not supported if we UserControl.

Comment: UserControl? Where is the code  you have written, forms or uwp client?

Comment: Hi,I was trying to create xamarin demo Project using Native UI, for that initally I created .net standard class Library and add New UWP Project ,I was trying to Give  Image source Path From Class Library Folder in UWP Xmal

Comment: This is My UWP Xmal                                                                                      <Page
    x:Class="UwpNativeUi.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UwpNativeUi"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
     <StackPanel>
         <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/SharedUICode;Component/Image/AppLogo.png"/>
     </StackPanel>
</Page>

Comment: If you used native project, please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687954/7254781) to get image source from .net standard lib.

Comment: Thanks Nico Zhu  <ImageBrush 
                                      ImageSource="ms-appx:///Image/AppLogoicon.png" 
                                      Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                       x:Name="Image"
                                    />  it's work for Me